# How can I log in from one app to the other with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, ddp

I have two meteor apps. one will have all the users data and the other is just a client app which handles some processing and exchanges data with the server app. the server app also have some user interface.
I have **two problems** with this configuration:

**First one** is I want to login from the client app but using meteor.users database stored in the server app. I read about [AccountsCommon](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html) but I can't get the sense of how to make a login ui which uses the `AccountsClient`. I tried for example to create `AccountsClient` at template loading with this line:

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
    ...
    accountObj = new AccountsClient({ddpUrl: "http://server-url"})
    ...
}
```

Then I tried to use it with accounts-ui call in my template html file:
`{{> loginButtons}}`

What I don't know is how to configure accounts-ui with the client object I created.

**Second one** is that what I want to do after fixing the first problem is to allow a user who is logged in from the server-app user interface to be redirected to the client-app without them needing to login again. i.e. (you click a button at the server-app that redirects you to the client-app and you're still logged-in in the client app).

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear in the doco, but perhaps the usual methods are available on AccountsClient and AccountsServer - have you tried it?

Comment: what do you mean by the 'usual methods' ?

Comment: I mean the methods that are available on the Accounts object, as per the Meteor doco. It suggests that the documented functions are not the complete set, so these other methods may be available here too (in fact they have to be, otherwise there would be no way to use them)